# Why does filtering on index of a dataframe not return the corresponding index values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have an X_train length of 81,000. I also have a boolean mask of the same length. I want to return the indices of where the mask is True by the following:

```
label_true_idx = np.arange(len(y_train))[bool_mask]
label_true_idx
```

which prints:

```
array([  131,   306,   332, ..., 80901, 80912, 80945])
```

However when i filter on this boolean mask:

```
 X_train[bool_mask].sort_index()
```

the index returned is:

Int64Index([   59,    72,    83,    85,   224,   227,   284,   311,   319,
399,

my question is why is the index not corresponding to the above 131,306.. am i missing something here?

Comment: Is there default index? try `X_train = X_train.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: When i do that then do X_train[bool_mask].sort_index() it is same as original indices 131,,, etc. Thank you